# XML namespace and XmlNamespaceManager c#

Tags: c#, xml

I've a little problem..

I'm using XmlNamespaceManager to parse a contex with unknown namespace..

It works really fine but I've a problem...

This is a snapshop of the generated XML

```
<RecordingConfig b:topic="true" xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1">
      <JobState b:topic="true">
...
      </JobState>
    </RecordingConfig>
```

It's ok.. but I'd a little change like this:

```
<tns1:RecordingConfig b:topic="true" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1">
      <tns1::JobState b:topic="true">
...
      </tns1:JobState>
    </tns1:RecordingConfig>
```

(look the prefix tns1:)

Someone can help me, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For removing namespace you have to write some 15 lines of code.

Easily you can do if you know the Xmlns then just replace

xdoc is your xml File then,

```
xdoc.LoadXml(xdoc.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics\"", ""));
```

then you can select any node

```
var node = xdoc.SelectNodes("RecordingConfig/JobState");
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. I resolved adding direcly an attribute :)